# Get first value of column without using TOP 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table who have this columns

```
+------------+-----------+
| ProjectKey | DesignKey |
+------------+-----------+
|       3978 |      6352 |
|       3978 |      6353 |
|       3978 |      6354 |
+------------+-----------+
```

I want to get only first `designkey` of one projectkey so I try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT* FROM PROJECTDESIGN WHERE PROJECTKEY = 3978
```

But it returns me all rows

I also try:

```
SELECT * FROM PROJECTDESIGN WHERE PROJECTKEY = 3978 GROUP BY ProjectKey, DesignKey
```

But it still return all rows

What I need to do to get only first row without using `TOP 1`. I want without TOP 1 because this is just an example my table can have multiple ProjectKey, so instead of get something like this:

```
+------------+-----------+
| ProjectKey | DesignKey |
+------------+-----------+
|       3978 |      6352 |
|       3978 |      6353 |
|       3978 |      6354 |
|       4000 |      2568 |
|       4000 |      2590 |
|       3000 |      6600 |
+------------+-----------+
```

My desire result is:

```
+------------+-----------+
| ProjectKey | DesignKey |
+------------+-----------+
|       3978 |      6352 |
|       4000 |      2568 |
|       3000 |      6600 |
+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Does "first" mean "minimum", or is there some other way to determine the order of the rows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one option using `row_number`:

```
select *
from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by projectkey order by designkey) rn
    from projectdesign
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you just want the minimum per group:

```
select ProjectKey, min(DesignKey) as "FirstDesignKey"
from ProjectDesign
group by ProjectKey;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option on just getting the minimum DesignKey for each ProjectKey

```
DECLARE @Project TABLE
    (
        [ProjectKey] BIGINT
      , [DesignKey] BIGINT
    );

INSERT INTO @Project (
                         [ProjectKey]
                       , [DesignKey]
                     )
VALUES ( 3978, 6352 )
     , ( 3978, 6353 )
     , ( 3978, 6354 )
     , ( 4000, 2568 )
     , ( 4000, 2590 )
     , ( 3000, 6600 );

SELECT DISTINCT [ProjectKey]
              , MIN([DesignKey]) OVER ( PARTITION BY [ProjectKey] ) AS [DesignKey]
FROM   @Project;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your try you should have `GROUP BY` only by `ProjectKey`
And then `DesignKey` could be taken as e.g. `min(DesignKey)`

(I assume that you want the smalles `DesignKey` for each distinct `ProjectKey` - what fits presented by you expected results)

```
SELECT
    ProjectKey,
    min(DesignKey) as DesignKey
FROM
    PROJECTDESIGN
GROUP BY
    ProjectKey
```

You can also take `DesignKey` in any (more complicated) way: `cross apply` would be helpfull:

```
select
    A.ProjectKey,
    B.DesignKey
from
    (select distinct ProjectKey from PROJECTDESIGN) A
    cross apply
    (
        select top 1 DesignKey from PROJECTDESIGN B
        where A.ProjectKey = B.ProjectKey
        order by DesignKey asc
    ) B
```

Here `cross apply` will try to fit one row for each distinct ProjectKey from table A.
It produces the same as previest example, however inside where you can pleace more sofisticated conditions. Order column could be changed.

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21219704)